# Replacing leaking Scalemaster scale inhibitor

Tags: plumbing, water, boiler

I've just discovered that my "Scalemaster Electrolytic Speedfit Scale Inhibitor" has a pin prick leak in it.

This device is sat between a copper pipe going to the combi boiler (I have assumed)

I've ordered a replacement with the intention of replacing it myself as it looks dead simple to do. However, I know absolutely nothing about plumbing.

Are there any pitfalls I could run into when attempting to replace it? Is there going to be an "air lock" situation?

My plan is simply to:

1. Turn off the water (which I've tested does stop the leak)
2. Take off the scalemaster
3. Put new scalemaster on
4. Turn the water on.

Is there anything I should be aware of? Am I incorrectly assuming it will be this simple?

Here is the knackered one:
[image: Knackered Scalemaster]

Replacement on order:
[image: Replacement]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plan is decent, but I'd amend it slightly:

1. Turn off the water
2. Take off the scalemaster and throw it away
3. Replace with a couple couplings and a regular piece of pipe
4. Turn the water on.
5. *Be happy you saved your money by not buying [a pointless device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_water_treatment)*

Comment: Your own Wiki link states "Whilst some are effective, such as **electrolytic devices**, most do not work." The Scalemaster this home owner has is an electrolytic device.

Comment: Well as long as I'm not doing anything stupid, I'm just gonna replace it as it seems the easiest thing to do

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the unit has been damaged on installation, likely heat damage. The product is plastic so heat is going to cause a problem. It does state this in the instructions. Follow the instructions in the box and you won't go wrong. DO NOT subject the unit to direct heat, chemicals or other corrosive materials.